# Unhandled exception at 0x008D5331 in zadanie XLVIII.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++, access-violation

I get this message and I can't figure out what can it be:

"Unhandled exception at 0x008D5331 in zadanie XLVIII.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC."

It's probably with string conversion can I get a tip?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//deklaracje
char ** fun_tablica();
char * tablica[10];
char ** linijka;

int main()
{
    fun_tablica();
    string b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    *linijka = new char[80];
    *linijka = "to jest linijka nr";
    b = to_string(i);
    cout << *linijka << b << endl;
    linijka++;
    }


    system("pause");
    return(0);
}


char ** fun_tablica() //ważne jest w deklaracji funkcji zwracajacej wskaznik aby okreslic typ jaki bedzie zwracac funkcja wzgledem typu na jaki wskazuje wskaznik
{
char * tablica[10];
linijka = tablica;
return linijka;
}
```

Comment: You need to seriously analyze your code as it violates many rules. You allocate but don't care of freeing memory. You are not properly using `char*` type variables, and return pointers to a stack memory (in `fun_tablica()`) which will disappear the moment function returns. Do you really need to use `fun_tablica()` to 'allocate' your memory? If you do then why do you declare `char * tablica[10];` one more time in `fun_tablica()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You get access error on 0xcccccccc when trying to use an uninitialized pointer when the compiler options are set for debug build. Grzegorz already mentioned some problems with the program.